How to persist data in React even between mounts/unmounts
In one of my React components, I need to make an initial external call to an API to load some countries data (name, iso, flag, etc.) to fill a dropdown select.
That call and data return take almost a second every time, so it is only acceptable for me to have the user waiting in loading state only the first time the component renders.
Then, although that component is re-rendered or even unmounted an mounted again, I would like to persist countries data.
I was thinking in React's useMemo hook for that, but it seems it only persists data between rerenders. Mounting/unmounting the component does not get me covered.
Any ideas about how could this be done?
Thanks in advance.

You could use a Redux store, store it in the state of a parent component that does not get unmounted, or maybe use localstorage. But these are just off the top of my head, someone might come along with a better solution if these do not suffice

Thanks, @LazyJ. Your comment gives me some ideas from where to start searching.

You can use react-query

It looks like the most cost-effective option for me was to store countries data as part of the parent's component state, that doesn't get unmounted. Thanks everyone. Solved.

You can create a hook for this requirement by persisting data in the localStorage.
const key = "countryData"
const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
  const jsonValue = localStorage.getItem(key)
  if {(jsonValue != null) return JSON.parse(jsonValue)}
  else {
   const countries = await getCountires();
   return countries;
}
})

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
}, [value])

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ThXsUwLWvc&t=23s This video explains how to create a hook.
Or you can directly refer to the local storage.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

I updated the answer, really appreciate your guidance.
